# Not able to setData in state ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

```jsx
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Inventory = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [repo, setRepo] = useState([]);
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
  }

  function addData() {
    let items = [...repo, data];
    setRepo(items);
  }
  console.log(repo, "data");
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label>Code</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="code"
          value={data.code}
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></input>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={data.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></input>
        <button onClick={() => addData()}>Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Inventory;
```

Debugging shows data is beings set to repo but then automatically changing to default value without any error

Comment: Your form is being submitted. Add `type="button"` to your `<button>` (or remove the `<form>` tag if you're not interested in its related functionality)